# how can i write syntax error in a file on php?

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error

I want to catch syntax error, run time error on php. This error write a log file.

I want to catch this type of error.

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'trigger_error' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\test\PHPPage.php on line 20

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the error reporting?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: i added this but it does not work.

<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

echo 'fffffffffffffffffff' //waant to catch this syntax error.

echo $a;

?>